# What is the use of the theorem on expection on a function of a random variable?

Tags: probability, expected-value, applications

If $X$ is a random variable, then the expectation of $X$ is defined as

$$E[X] = \sum_{x} x p_{X}(x)$$

Where $p_X$ is a pmf on $X$.

If $g$ is a real valued function then I learn the following theorem

$$E[g(X)] = \sum_{x} g(x)p_X(x)$$

I know only a single use of the above theorem:

**It is used to calculate the expectation of a new random variable $g(X)$ without calculating the pmf of $g(X)$ but by using the pmf of $X$ i.e., $p_X(x)$.**

Is there any other use or application for the theorem other than the one mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's the "only" use for it, but it's a big "only", because it allows you to perform arbitrary transformations of random variables and calculate their expectation without needing to directly derive their probability distributions.

This is important for things like manipulating the formulas for variance and covariance, since you need to deal with terms like $E(X^2)$. It also opens the way to distributions like the log-normal distribution, since it's defined as $Y = \exp(X), X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other use or application for the theorem other than the one mentioned above?

The Law of the Unconscious Statistician is used exclusively for that, but as @ConMan answered, that is a most frequent and much useful application.

---

For any discrete random variable $X$ (with pmf $p_{\small X}$) and any function $g$ where the expectation of $g(X)$ is real, we have that it is: $\mathsf E(g(X))=\sum_x g(x)\,p_{\small X}(x)$

Let $Y=g(X)$, so thence $Y$ will have probability:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(g(X)\tag 1&=\mathsf E(Y)\\[1ex]\tag 2&={\sum}_y y\,p_{\small g(X)}(y)\\[1ex]\tag 3&={\sum}_y\,y{\sum}_{x~:~y=g(x)}p_{\small X}(x)\\[1ex]\tag 4&={\sum}_y\,{\sum}_{x~:~y=g(x)} g(x)\,p_{\small X}(x)\\[1ex]\tag 5&={\sum}_x g(x)\,p_{\small X}(x) \end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$

An analogous proof can be done for continuous random variables too.

---

- $(2)$ is by Law of Total Probability.  The probability mass of $\{Y=y\}$ equals the sum of the probability masses of $\{X=x\}$ for all $x$ where $x=g(y)$.